# How to find actual unique values in pandas DataFrame that match a regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, normalization

I have a pandas DataFrame with over a million rows and I need to find all unique values (for a given column) in the process of trying to normalise the data. The data in the given column is of type string - representing city names - and I have come a long way already in normalising the data, by taking certain steps as lower-casing all values in the column, striping and used `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.replace()` using regular expressions that seemed obvious for the data.

A sample of what I have ( and I want to achieve) found below:

```
In [1018]: sample
Out[1018]: 
       0
0     warsaw   ## -> warsaw
1     krakow   ## -> krakow
2   warszawa   ## -> warsaw
3   cracovie   ## -> krakow
4    warsawa   ## -> warsaw
5      krkow   ## -> krakow
6     krąków   ## -> krakow
7   krakowie   ## -> krakow
8     kraków   ## -> krakow
9   varşovia   ## -> warsaw
10  warschau   ## -> warsaw
```

only much bigger set of data than this, such that I need to search for variations of different city names using reg expressions in order to find all existing in the dataset versions and proceed with the normalisation.

```
In [1023]: df.column_a.unique()
Out[1023]: 
array(['warsaw', 'bydgoszcz', 'null', ..., 'kłodawa', 'kościelna wieś',
   'poznań-jeżyce'], dtype=object)

In [1024]: len(df.column_a.unique())
Out[1024]: 3798
```

I have tried with `.str.contains()` but I am only getting a boolean for those indices that have - under the defined column - values that match the given regex:

```
In [1029]: df.column_a.str.contains(r"\bwar.*")
Out[1029]: 
0       True
1      False
2      False
3       True
4      False
5      False
6      False
7      False
8      False
9      False
10     False
   ...
```

However, what I'm looking for is to get the actual values that match the given regex. For the above example I would like to be able to get something like:

```
['warsaw','warszawa','warsawa','warschau']
```

Comment: This will be a massive pain in the a$$, you have to lower-case, normalise the spellings, compute some kind of similarity such as levenshtein or jaccard but on top of this you have entries in different languages!! If you have access to some kind of dictionary then you can map these entries and normalise them to the same root word

Comment: I'd imagine that actually doing all of this with regex would be *terribly* slow.

Comment: @n1c9 Running `df.column_a = df.column_a.str.lower()` and `df.column_a = df.column_a.str.strip()` is in fact very quick. I only have to do this once anyways, not interested in how well the solution performs in the long term.

Comment: @EdChum Yes, the data needs some serious cleaning, you're right. If I had the actual values returned by a regex I would be able to move A LOT faster, by running something like: `pattern = r"^.*\b(?P<WORD>warsaw)\b.*$"`, `replace_with = r"\1"` and then `df.replace({'column_a':pattern},{'column_a':replace_with}, regex=True, inplace=True)` Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean indexing -- refer to [document](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
   In [143] df[df.column_a.str.contains(r'\bwar.*')]
   Out [143]
   0     warsaw
   2   warszawa
   4    warsawa
   10  warschau
```

If there are null values then do this:

```
df[pd.notnull(df.column_a) & df.column_a.str.contains(r'\bwar.*')]
```

Comment: Thanks! I got en error trying that: `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`. I suppose I should try to replace all NaN values with empty string or similar.

Comment: Update the answer for - what if there are null values

Answer (score 1):

I have now found a way to run a search to return unique values in a DataFrame column. The solution is to `extract` the values instead.

For the problem, as described above, I have used `str.extract()` instead of what `str.contains()`

```
In [1311]: df.column_a.str.extract(r"\b(war.*)").unique()
Out[1311]: 
array(['warsaw', nan, 'waraszawa', 'warszawskiej', 'warszawy', 'warzawa',
   'warsza', 'warrszawa', 'warzszawa', 'warszawan', 'warszawie',
   'warwszawa', 'warszawski', 'warzno 84-208', 'warasza, wola',
   'warszawskie', 'warzsawa', 'warzno', 'warszawa', 'warszwa', 'warsawa'], dtype=object)
```

There might be a better solution, but this one sure is one.

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by many of the responses here for a similar problem, here is my approach.

For me I could not get the .str.contains().unique() approaching working, so here is my alternative.

We use a combination of techniques we subset by boolean indexing, remove NaN values from the str.contains, drop the duplicate values and finally export to a list

```
df[df["column_a"].str.contains(r"\bwar.*", na=False)]['column_a'].drop_duplicates().tolist()
```

I also extract the specific column, assuming for other post views, their data frame might contain more than 1 column, post boolean indexing.